# Creating ".t7" torch file in python

Tags: python, lua, pytorch, torch

By using pytorch, I can manage to save file like the following:

```
torch.save(object, "object.t7")
```

However, I cannot open it through Lua.

When I use the following command in Lua,

```
local info1 = torch.load("object.t7")
```

I receive the following error:

> /home/hasan/build/torch/install/bin/luajit:
>   ...an/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:315:
>   ...an/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:183:
>   [thread 4 callback]
>   ...e/hasan/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:375:
>   unknown object stack traceback:   [C]: in function 'error'
>     ...e/hasan/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:375: in
>   function 'readObject'
>     ...e/hasan/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/torch/File.lua:409: in
>   function 'load'
>     /home/hasan/GAN/icml2016/data/donkey_folder_txt_coco.lua:112: in
>   function 
>     [C]: in function 'xpcall'
>     ...an/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/threads.lua:234: in
>   function 'callback'
>     ...asan/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:65: in
>   function
>   <...asan/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:41>  [C]:
>   in function 'pcall'
>     ...asan/build/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/threads/queue.lua:40: in
>   function 'dojob'  [string "  local Queue = require
>   'threads.queue'..."]:15: in main chunk

I need to run a torch training in Lua, with preprocessed data through Pytorch.

Is there any way to save ".t7" file via pytorch, and open it through Lua?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not familia with Lua. But I guess the problem here is that PyTorch doesn't has it's own implementation for saving and loading the files. If you take a look at the [source of `torch.save`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/serialization.html#save) you see that it's just one line relying on pythons `pickle` module (`cPickle for Python2). So you probably need to look for a way opening pickled files in Lua. Alternatively you could just try another way of saving and loading without pickle.

Comment: *I think did not point out the main problem really well: `pickle` is just an other python module. So Lua Torch has probably a completely different implementation for saving files and loading files, not based on `pickle`.*